# Deleting a row in sqlite database on a click of a button

Tags: android, database, sqlite, delete-row

dhelper.java- the deleteshowById2 function is called on click of a button from the activity class function name delete Row, in this function the class context is passed and the name is also passed.

```
public static int deleteShowById2(String name, Context ctx) {

    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(ctx);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    String where = "showId='"+name+"'";
    return db.delete(TableName, where, null);


}
```

Activity class

```
public void deleteRow()
{
    name=e1.getText().toString();
    MyfirstPojo ob=new MyfirstPojo();
    ob.setName(name);
    int i=0;
    i=dheloper.deleteShowById2(name,this);
    if(i>0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "One Row Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
Button deletebutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    deletebutton.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1 :
        gettext();
        break;
    case R.id.button2 :
        Intent i=new      Intent(MyfirstdatabaseActivity.thiViewDetailsActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    case R.id.button3 :
        deleteRow();
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: can u explain `MyfirstdatabaseActivity.thiViewDetailsActivity.class` line?

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

You can't delete a row in a database that was opened in read only state. Use this instead:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

To this

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```